# AI positioning circles within an arc at equal distances and heights

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I am trying to create a simple visual, but I can't find a good way to align smaller blue circles within a larger arc. You can tell I've just kind of eye-balled it. Here is what I'm working with:
[image]
I tried using transform distort → transform and that was able to make copies of the circles very quickly, but in the end I couldn't find the "magic" number to move the circles about the arc. So back to square one.

### Question

Is there a more precise approach to place the blue circles around the arc at the center of each segment that I can bring to bear with AI? What would that be? I hope there is an easier way than my approach above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the circumference quarter is divided into 8 parts, the whole circle has 32 partitions.

- Place and select the first blue circle at the center of the first bottom left partition
- Press <kbd>R</kbd> to activate the **Rotation Tool**
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click at the rotation center (the big circle center)
- At the pop up rotate window, type = -360/32 → **Copy**
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Win to repeat the last transformation

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, when I try the circles are copied in place, they only rotate in place. They do not get transformed as in your answer. Also I noticed my transform object toggle is grayed out.

Comment: Incomplete answer, my mistake. Updated.

Comment: very cool! Any tips for making sure the first circle is in the center of the segment? I noticed if the first circle is off this method will be slightly off too.

Comment: @ArashHowaida, draw lines from corner to corner diagonally and snap to the object to the center of the X